# Primary Key in RDF data(Sesame Model API)

Tags: model, primary-key, rdf, semantic-web, sesame

I implemented the following method to check primary key in the Model API in Sesame. 
The idea is that for each class in RDF, we have different subject and these subjects should have a key or a set of keys (together as PK). ISBN for book or Family-Name and birth-date for Person are two examples.

Unfortunately the method that I have implemented is not efficient and needs at least 10 times more than a SPARQL query.

Is there any idea to make this method efficient?

```
public static boolean checkPK(Model triples, List<URI> properties) {

             Iterator<Resource> it = triples.subjects().iterator();
             Resource subject;
             boolean violation = false;
             int n = 0;
             HashSet<LinkedHashSet<Value>> results = new HashSet<LinkedHashSet<Value>>();
             while(it.hasNext())
             {
                 n++;
                 subject = it.next();
                 LinkedHashSet<Value> record = new LinkedHashSet<Value>();

         for(URI property: properties)  
           record.add(tempModel.filter(subject , property,null).objectValue());

                 results.add(record);
                 if(results.size() < n)
                    return true;

                }
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using SPARQL?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I would like to implement a method which is possibely efficienter than SPARQL. since this is the context of constraint checking and the first possible violation could stop the query.

Comment: if you plan on only using toy data, this might work. but as soon as you want a scalable solution, something hard coded over `Model` isn't going to cut it. You might just delegate this to a database because query answering is one of the things they're good at. There are also existing constraint validation solutions you could use instead of building one yourself

Comment: Apart from what's been said above I'd say that the way you copy elements from the model to lists is unnecessary and likely to severely slow things down. Try using the filter view function of Model to your advantage.

Comment: Thanks. do you mean something like this ?                                               if (tempModel.filter(subject , null,null).objects().equals(tempModel.filter(otherSubject , null,null).objects()))
   violation = true; 
   }

Comment: I honestly don't know, because I can't make heads nor tails on what your method is actually supposed to do. You have a boolean variable `violation`, but that never is used anywhere else. Instead your method simply seems to return `true` whenever it finds a property for a given subject that has less than `n` values (where `n` simply seems to be the ordinal number of the subject you're currently looking at). Try cleaning up your code example a bit, and try and explain what you _expect_ this method to check (i.e. for which cases should it return true, and for which cases false).